# Python float overflow, what happens when float overflows?

Tags: python, integer-overflow

I was looking at the output from the code below. When I increment 1 to the maximum value of float, the output seems to be what I would expect, but when I do x=x*1.5, then I see inf as the output which I would assume is the float overflow. My question is, at what upper limit does it go from expected output to inf?

```
x=sys.float_info.max
x=x+1
x
```

Comment: I don't think there is a consistent limit really.  `x ** 2` gets an error, but `x * x` does not.

Comment: @zondo - Well, there's a consistent limit in the sense that there is a maximum value that an IEE754 float can represent.

Comment: I'm not clear about what the question is.  Are you asking for the minimum `x` for which `sys.float_info.max + x` is  `inf`?

Comment: @DSM yes, but I think there is no definitive value for that based on Jaco's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python float  does not have sufficient precision to store the `+ 1` for `sys.float_info.max`, so the operations is effectively equivalent to adding zero. The below comparison actually returns `True`:

```
print sys.float_info.max+1==sys.float_info.max
```

Only when you start adding numbers that are large enough to result in a change in the IEE754 binary representation of that float, you will get `inf`, for example:

```
x+0.00000000000000001E308
```

returns `inf` on my machine (Windows 64bit)

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought, just wanted to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not having enough reputation to comment under the excellent answer given by Alex, but I think that it may mislead people coming here with different question on their mind, that is looking for the limit when incrementing stops to work as usually (i.e. stops actually incrementing), which is actually much much lower.

On my machine with current Python `sys.float_info.max` is `1.7976931348623157e+308`

When testing with the following code:

```
for a in range(300):
  x = float("1.0e"+str(a))
  if x != x+1:
    print(x)
```

it turns out that incrementing stops working for numbers exceeding roughly `1e+15`, because of the limited range of the [significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand).